# Postgres 9.6 - Updating text stored inside JSONB

Tags: postgresql

I have a database that contains lots of blobs of JSON that reference lots of offsite Images.

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE vendors (
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    images jsonb[],
    location jsonb,
    user_id uuid,
    created timestamp with time zone,
    updated timestamp with time zone
);
```

The JSON:

```
{ 
    "url": "http://domain.com/eid/id/file.jpg", 
    "title": "foo", 
    "eid": "eid", 
    "id": "id"
}
```

These images have now moved from http:// to https:// and I'd like to update to the data. I will eventually fully remove the domain so these are relative paths, thus avoiding this carnage!

I was thinking of doing something very crude, such as:

```
UPDATE vendors SET images = REPLACE(images, 'http://', 'https://');
```

However I am seeing the following error:

```
LINE 1: UPDATE vendors SET images = REPLACE(images, 'http://','https...
                                    ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I'm guessing the issue is the Type Casts part, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You need to show us the JSON structure of `images`.

Comment: type `ARRAY` that contains `JSONB`

Comment: Why a JSONB _array_?  Why not use a simple JSONB column that _contains_ an array of json elements? That's duplicated de-normalization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH https AS (
   SELECT v.id, array_agg(x.i) newimages
      FROM vendors v JOIN
           LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(
                      replace(to_jsonb(v.images)::text,
                              'http://',
                              'https://'
                      )::jsonb
                   ) x(i)
              ON TRUE
      GROUP BY v.id
)
UPDATE vendors v
   SET images = https.newimages
   FROM https
   WHERE v.id = https.id;
```